# REMOTE_REPORTING_MISSING_REMOTE_MODULE Itext 7.2.2

Tags: java, itext7, licensing

I am trying to consume an **itext 7.2 license** from java, however when loading it, it throws an exception of type: REMOTE_REPORTING_MISSING_REMOTE_MODULE

I have a .json file in C and I use **licensing-base** in **version 4.1.0**, please if someone could tell me what I might be doing wrong or if I'm missing something to do. Before doing a test with a temporary license and everything ok but when I use the paid license it throws an exception and doesn't let me continue.

In advance thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your license requires the usage of the remote reporting module iText provides.

You can add it to your project using Maven, or download the jar and manually include it. It can be found here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf.licensing/licensing-remote

More information on volume and remote reporting licenses can be found here:
https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/volume-counter-faqs

Please make sure you're using the correct licensing-base and licensing-remote versions for your version of iText.

A compatibility matrix can be found here:
https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/compatibility-matrix

Comment: Hello Matthias, I appreciate your kind response.

I have followed the recommendations that you have made me, put version 4.0.3 in both licensing-base and licensing-remote libraries in the order that I mention here, however the error continues to appear, I use those versions because according to the compatibility table that you kindly share with me is compatible with the itext 7.2.2 core, is there any other element that I am missing? First of all I insert the version of the itext7-core 7.2.2 library, maybe the order can affect the behavior.

Comment: Hey @CemailSn, thanks for the update. It seems that you're adding the correct libraries to work with the iText SDK to your project, so I suspect there might be some configuration issue. Since you're a paying iText customer, my best recommendation would be to create a ticket on https://itext.freshdesk.com/ so the support team can investigate this further. It would be beneficial if you could create a MCVE test project so the team can reproduce and further investigate this. Would that be possible?

Comment: Hello @Matthias Keisse, I don't know how to create the project that you mention, however a couple of hours ago I raised a ticket in the itext support now I have to wait 3 business days to see the answer they give me, I basically put the same question complementing it with the use of your kind response, in the same way I appreciate your support now it's time to wait and keep checking in case I find something new.

Greetings.